# Entity Framework Saving new Objects Returns a Populated ID?

Tags: entity-framework

Please help me understand this.

When I save a new object to the database (using Entity Framework), am I able to access the newly created ID (Identity column) value in the line(s) after I call db.SaveChanges()?

```
public Class TheObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}

.....

TheObject MyObject = new TheObject();
MyObject.FirstName = "John";

db.TheObjects.Add(MyObject);
db.SaveChanges();

int MyNewID = MyObject.ID; //Am I able to access MyObject.ID here and have access to the value that was just created in the database?
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are but why not just run that code and test it yourself?

Comment: Hi Sean.  I wanted further confirmation as this is what I am seeing but was not expecting it to do this.  Mainly, I did not realize that objects did not need to be re-retrieved from the database after the save (different from the old ADO.NET world of database access).